# Unable to install phpunit ,Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 6.5.8

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, dbunit

I have php 7.0.29 version installed on my vagrant setup on windows 10.

When I run following command

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit
```

I get errors as mentioned

```
Using version ^6.5 for phpunit/phpunit
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 6.5.8
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 6.5.7
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 6.5.6
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 6.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 6.5.4
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 6.5.3
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 6.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/phpunit 6.5.1
    - phpunit/dbunit 2.0.3 conflicts with phpunit/phpunit[6.5.0].
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.0 conflicts with phpunit/dbunit[2.0.3].
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.0 conflicts with phpunit/dbunit[2.0.3].
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ^6.5 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 6.5.6, 6.5.7, 6.5.8].
    - Installation request for phpunit/dbunit (locked at 2.0.3, required as ^2.0) -> satisfiable by phpunit/dbunit[2.0.3].
```

My composer.json file has following code

```
{
    "name": "tsawler/acme",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "xyz",
            "email": "xyz@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "filp/whoops": "2.0.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~1.1",
        "illuminate/database": "5.1.*",
        "altorouter/altorouter": "1.1.0",
        "respect/validation": "~1.0",
        "duncan3dc/blade": "2.2.*",
        "robmorgan/phinx": "^0.4.5",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^2.7",
        "cocur/slugify": "^1.2",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^5.4",
        "kunststube/csrfp": "^0.1.0",
        "sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser": "v1.5.0",
        "rdlowrey/auryn": "1.1.*",
        "fabpot/goutte": "^3.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": { "Acme\\": "src/" }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.1",
        "phpunit/php-invoker": "^1.1",
        "phpunit/dbunit": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Either check if PHP 7.0 is high enough for this repository requirements and if so, try to remove the composer.lock file and install again.

Comment: @hakre  I deleted composer.lock file and tried again but it did not help

Comment: Then it looks like that the packages you require are not compatible to each other. Is there anything special requiring these versions?

Comment: @hakre I don't think I need specific version. I am  following a tutorial and first time using php unit as well as composer. Do you have any suggestion to fix this ?

Comment: Please share the full content of your `composer.json`.

Comment: @rob006 I have updated the question with complete composer.json

Comment: Why are you manually requiring `phpunit/php-invoker` and `phpunit/dbunit`? Shouldn't `phpunit/phpunit` suffice?

Answer (score 7):

- I got this error when trying to upgrade my phpunit by requiring it again. Solution for me was to uninstall phpunit and reinstall it:

  ```
        $ composer remove phpunit/phpunit --dev
        $ composer require phpunit/phpunit --dev
  ```

Comment: sorry, let me try to improve my answers

Answer (score 1):

You are requiring old versions of:

```
"phpunit/php-invoker": "^1.1",
"phpunit/dbunit": "^2.0"
```

Yet phpunit requires more up to date version of those dependencies as it tells you here:

```
- phpunit/dbunit 2.0.3 conflicts with phpunit/phpunit[6.5.0].
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.0 conflicts with phpunit/dbunit[2.0.3].
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.0 conflicts with phpunit/dbunit[2.0.3]
```

Only require `phpunit/phpunit`, instead and let composer handle its dependencies instead of requiring each dependency.

Comment: I will try and inform

Comment: I removed  "phpunit/php-invoker": "^1.1",
"phpunit/dbunit": "^2.0" but no success

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. I did

```
composer remove symfony/phpunit-bridge --dev
```

after that, I reinstalled it by doing

```
composer require --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge
```

and then

```
php bin/phpunit
```